# Grafana/Postgresql: how to convert date stored in UTC to local timezone

Tags: postgresql, timezone, grafana

I have a date stored in postgres db, e.g. `2019-09-03 15:30:03`. Timezone of postgres is UTC.

When Grafana gets the date, it is `2020-09-03T15:30:03.000000Z`. If I now run date_trunc('day', `2020-09-03T15:30:03.000000Z`), I get `2020-09-03T00:00:00.000000Z`. But, I want midnight in my local timezone.

1. How do I get the local timezone (offset) in postgres or grafana?
2. Could I get the timezone in military style, instead of "Z" for UTC "B"?
3. Or can I somehow subtract the offset of the local timezone to get a UTC date corresponding to midnight local time?

Thanks in advance
Michael

Comment: Grafana converts UTC DB result to the dashboard timezone automatically. By default local browser time zone is used, but you can change that in the dashboard configuration - for example to UTC, from Grafana 7+ you can set any time zone for the dashboard. So do you really need to return local time zone from the PostgreSQL, when you can use Grafana dashboard time zone feature?

Comment: The problem is, that I want to "date_trunc('month', start_date). That truncates the date according to the timezone of the (Grafana) client resp. the postgres server timezone. I want to have it trucated according to the displayed timezone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Get the local timezone (offset):

```
select to_char(now(), 'OF');
-- result '+03' for EEST
```

Get UTC time corresponding to midnight local time:

```
select date_trunc('DAY', now()) at time zone 'UTC';
-- result '2020-06-05 21:00:00.0' for 13:30 EEST on 2020-06-06
```

Convert UTC time to local timezone time:

```
select now();
-- Local time is 2020-06-06 13:43:27.482463
select (now() at time zone 'UTC');
-- UTC time is 2020-06-06 10:43:27.482463

select '2020-06-06 10:43:27.482463UTC'::timestamp with time zone; 
-- UTC time converted to local time is 2020-06-06 13:43:27.482463
```

Hope that this helps.